# Place View at bottom of a screen/layout using a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, gravity, android-layout-weight

I am trying to place a TableRow with two Buttons at the bottom of the screen, under other view elements in the layout, but if I put there, the TableRow dissappear out of the screen. I I put at top or in the middle, no problem.

I was trying a lot of layout_gravity, gravity and weight combinations, but I can't get it.

[image: screenshot of the layout]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:text="@string/traza" 
    android:layout_margin="10sp"/>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reiniciar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/bordebutton"
            android:text="@string/reiniciar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/comprobar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/bordebutton"
            android:text="@string/comprobar" />

    </TableRow>

<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    android:id="@+id/gestures"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadeEnabled="true"
    android:fadeOffset="3000"
    android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
    android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **RelativeLayout** to achieve this.

There you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/traza"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reiniciar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bordebutton"
            android:text="@string/reiniciar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/comprobar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bordebutton"
            android:text="@string/comprobar" />
    </TableRow>

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gestures"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
        android:fadeEnabled="true"
        android:fadeOffset="3000"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it crashes :( 04-21 17:05:06.363: E/AndroidRuntime(20964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.hsk.ap/es.hsk.ap.juega.Trazos}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.gesture.GestureOverlayView

Comment: then remove `android.gesture.GestureOverlayView` from your layout, clean the project and then run it. Actually I didnt add **GestureOverlayView** to the layout myself, it was already mentioned in your layout. If its crashing then how were you able to run it?

Comment: It crashes when I change LineaLayout to RelativeLayout as you said at first. I can't remove this view, I need it. And the problem isn't it, it happens if you use other layout in the middle, like a imageview

Comment: dont simply replace the word LinearLayout with RelativeLayout... just copy the entire xml in my answer and replace it to the one you have...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Your root element should be a `TableLayout` if you want to use the features contained in that `View`. You currently have it as a `LinearLayout`.

I don't see anything mentioning how non `TableRow` Views are vertically placed in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

From my experience, a `TableLayout` will always place things directly below the last row.

Have tried using a `RelativeLayout`, or `LinearLayout` to accomplish what you need? It is much more flexible than a `TableLayout`.

You could also close your `TableLayout` and place a `LinearLayout` below it.

Comment: I have tried a LinearLayout instead TableRow, but same problem, the object view on it, use all the screen size. I want to use all the avaible screen, but with these two buttons visible at bottom of layout. Thanks!